# I need help installing Openmeeting 3.1.5

Tags: server

I am having difficulty installing Open meeting on Ubuntu 16.04. The only documentation I find refers to Ubuntu MATE. Is MATE required?

Comment: https://openmeetings.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: What kind of difficulties do you have installing it?

Comment: I get to installing SOX, it and nothing beyond want to install there are missing packages, which leads me to believe it requires MATE but I am sure I don't want to go in that direction. I have other servers and want them on the same platform.

Comment: You need to provide us with more information of what kind of missing packages it complains about.. I followed the instructions myself on Ubuntu 16.04 and I didn't have any problems installing Sox.

Answer (score 0):

No, MATE is not be required. They have instructions on their website on how to install OpenMeetings 3.1.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

[Installation OpenMeetings 3.1.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27838216/Installation%20OpenMeetings%203.1.5%20on%20Ubuntu%2016.04%20LTS.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1485767975000&api=v2)

It seem to be very extensive to install.